# How to apply ckeditor in django board site articleapp

Tags: html, django, web, ckeditor

[image]]

[image]

[image]

I tried to add ckeditor to my django board project articleapp following a tutorial lecture, but I'm having issues with image files not loading and the articleapp's upload function not working at all... i checked config/setting.py 's  media and static root,
but I can't find:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('home')
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('accountapp:login')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref`
```